# SetValue not working to set the value of a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a very simple macro in Google Sheets to get the month value and write it in a cell on the sheet. But for some reason the month value is not getting written to the cell.

```
function Macro1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'), true);
  var today = new Date;
  var prevMonth = Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+1', 'MMMM yy');
  var cell = spreadsheet.getRange('G12');
  cell.setValue = prevMonth;
  Logger.log(prevMonth);
  Logger.log(cell.getValue());
 };
```

I can see the value of **prevMonth** in the log. It is correct but no value is getting written in the actual cell and hence, the last line also returns blank.
And yes, I have read-write access on the sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setValue is a function, so you need to pass parameter to it.

```
function Macro1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'), true);
  var today = new Date();
  var prevMonth = Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+1', 'MMMM yy');
  var cell = spreadsheet.getRange('G12');
  cell.setValue(prevMonth);
  Logger.log(prevMonth);
  Logger.log(cell.getValue());
}
```

cell.setValue(prevMonth);